# pgfplots: How to overwrite macros in a loop for calculating domain-values

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, foreach, loops, pgfmath

I want to draw several arcs (from percentages) in a loop. The following arc should connect to the previous one: 
`50% (Start=0, End=180°), then 25% (Start=180°, End=180°+90°),....`

How do I do it correctly with the loop?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every path/.style={very thick},
%declare function={Start(\x)=(\Start)*3.6;
%End(\x)=(Start(\x)+\x)*3.6+1;}
]
% Start Values
\pgfmathsetmacro\Start{0}
\pgfmathsetmacro\End{0}

\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle, axis equal, title=Actual]
\foreach \Percent/\Color in {50/blue, 25/red}{

\pgfmathsetmacro\Start{\End}
\pgfmathsetmacro\End{(\Start+\Percent)*3.6}

\edef\temp{%
\noexpand\addplot[domain=\Start:\End, draw=\Color]({2*cos(x)}, {2*sin(x)})  coordinate[pos=0, label=S\Start](liStart) coordinate[label=E\End](liEnd);
}\temp}
 \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every path/.style={very thick},]
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle, axis equal, title=Target]
\addplot[domain=0:180, draw=blue]({2*cos(x)}, {2*sin(x)});
\addplot[domain=180:270, draw=red]({2*cos(x)}, {2*sin(x)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped`, and there was a logical issue:

```
\pgfmathsetmacro\End{(\Start+\Percent)*3.6}
```

is wrong because it multiplies *everything* by `3.6` but you want only to multiply `\Percent`.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every path/.style={very thick},
%declare function={Start(\x)=(\Start)*3.6;
%End(\x)=(Start(\x)+\x)*3.6+1;}
]
% Start Values
\pgfmathsetmacro\Start{0}
\pgfmathsetmacro\End{0}

\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle, axis equal, title=Actual]
\pgfplotsforeachungrouped \Percent/\Color in {50/blue, 25/red}{

\pgfmathsetmacro\Start{\End}
\pgfmathsetmacro\End{\Start+\Percent*3.6}
\edef\temp{%
\noexpand\addplot[domain=\Start:\End, draw=\Color,smooth]({2*cos(x)}, {2*sin(x)})  coordinate[pos=0, label=S\Start](liStart) coordinate[label=E\End](liEnd);
}\temp}
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW, I did not attempt to make the output more pretty by avoiding the clips.

Comment: Wow, this was very fast, Mr. Cat. I will read ;)

Comment: Ohh, `pgfplotsforeachungrouped ` allows maximal 2 arguments, right?  I fear, I need 3-4 arguments.

Comment: @cis Well, at least you may understand why some users are hesitant to upvote your questions. How often did you ask a question, get an answer that answers the question, and then you change the requirements. (I personally do not think you need so many arguments. Rather you can use a cycle list, or other lists.)

Comment: I need 3 arguments: `\Percent/\Color/\Text`

Comment: Well, you can always ask a new question. Changing a question that has an answer is not something I am really excited about. (You can use your code with the `remember` key, but I am not going to spell this in this thread.)